# Erlang list comprehension

Tags: erlang, variable-assignment, list-comprehension

I'm testing an expression with two inequalities for the condition of a list comprehension. Is there a way to have assignments here and not duplicate that expression?

The following code doesn't work, but I wish it would:

```
diagnose(Expertise,PatientSymptoms) ->
    {[CertainDisease||
         {CertainDisease,KnownSymptoms}<-Expertise,
         C=length(PatientSymptoms)-length(PatientSymptoms--KnownSymptoms),
         C>=2,
         C<=5      
      ]}.
```

Comment: {NewDisease}=diagnose([{d1,[s1,s2,s3]},{d2,[s1,s2,s3,s4]}],[s1,s2,s4])  Does this answer you question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A way of writing it directly without a `fun` would be to use a `begin ... end` block ending with a boolean test:

```
[ CertainDisease || {CertainDisease,KnownSymptoms} <- Expertise,
                    begin
                        C = length(PatientSymptoms) - length(PatientSymptoms -- KnownSymptoms),
                        C >= 2 andalso C <= 5
                    end ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Define a filter function; this way, it is invoked once per element, eliminating your duplication of calculating `C`:

```
Filter = fun({CertainDisease, KnownSymptoms}) ->
    C = length(PatientSymptoms) - length(PatientSymptoms--KnownSymptoms),
    C >= 2 andalso C <= 5       
end
```

And use it in your list comprehension like so:

```
[CertainDisease ||
    {CertainDisease,KnownSymptoms} <- Expertise,
    Filter({CertainDisease, KnownSymptoms})      
]
```

Comment: Should work as long as the filter `fun` is in the same dynamic scope as `PatientSymptoms`. That's what I was asking about it a minute ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn assignments into singleton generators:

```
{[CertainDisease||
     {CertainDisease,KnownSymptoms} <- Expertise,
     C <- [length(PatientSymptoms)-length(PatientSymptoms--KnownSymptoms)],
     C >= 2,
     C <= 5      
]}.
```