# What is begin...end in Erlang used for?

Tags: erlang, expression, block

I just stomped at a `begin...end` in Erlang's documentation ([here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79819)), but it doesn't give some examples of how it is useful.

Looking here in StackOverflow I found two cases where people would be using `begin...end`, both in list comprehensions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5645116/979505
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5141263/979505

But I wonder if there are more of such uses.

Can anyone provide another scenario in which a `begin...end` is useful in Erlang?

Thanks

Comment: you can just use it to create quick code to evaluate and create the value you want. e.g.  `T = {1,2,begin 1+2 end}.` will evalute `T={1,2,3}`

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua But your example works even without begin end. Can anyone give an example that actually requires using being end? Or are they like curly brackets?

Comment: @Aus check the answers below, there are examples that cannot be accomplished without begin...end

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Macros, for example:

```
-define(M(A, B),
    begin
        C = foo(),
        bar(A, B, C)
    end).
```

Comment: Thanks @P_A. Some clarifications so others don't have to test what I just tested. A macro with more than one expression can be made without `begin...end`. But, if you are using that macro in a place where only one element is expected (like in `io:format`) then `begin...end` is the way to go.

Comment: How is this better than -define(M(A, B), bar(A, B, foo())). ?

Comment: It's just an example to show how `begin...end` can be used

Answer (score 9):

To evaluate a catch (always the same idea to have multiple expression reduced to one)

```
Res = (catch
    begin
        C = foo(Bar),
        io:format("evaluation of C ok~n"),
        D = bar(A, B, C)
     end),
```

Answer (score 5):

As previous answerers mentioned, this construct is used whenever you need to have multiple expressions but only one is allowed.

However, the majority of such cases would be considered a stinky style. I can remember only a few of places where a single expression is expected: an argument in a function call, `catch` expression, `case of`, `try of` and list comprehension. All of them except for list comprehension shouldn't be used with `begin end` construct because the variables are leaking to the outer scope probably causing the subsequent bindings to become matches.

List comprehension expression is different because it is transformed to a separate function with its own scope and no variable introduced in `begin end` leaks to the outer scope.

Comment: In which part of `try of` ? in each of the 3 segments of a `try...of...catch` we can put several instructions.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I thought only one expression is allowed in `try <here> of ... catch ... end` expression. Actually this works fine: `try a = b, b of A -> A catch C:E -> {C,E} end.`. Thanks!

Comment: @Aus Wrong in what? The answer proposes the only valid usage of `begin end` is in list comprehensions. And as `try of` allows multiple expressions `begin end` has even less applications even if you don't care about the quality of the code.

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev In your answer you wrote "case of" takes a single expression, and MondKin said it does not. "case of" takes multiple true/false  conditions as a single expression, but you cannot run an assignment statement for example before a true/false condition, see my answer below. What I wanted to say is that you are correct, however the definition of "expression" wasn't so clear.

Answer (score 2):

According to erlang documentation is it block expression that evaluates each expression but returns only the last one.

See this example (not using block expression):

```
A = 1,
case A + 1 of
    3 ->
        ok;
    _->
        nop
end.

% returns ok
```

Now you can define A within the case argument using block expression:

```
case begin A = 1, A + 1 end of
    3 ->
        ok;
    _->
        nop
end.

%returns ok
```

That evaluates A = 1, then returns the result of A + 1.

Now we know that this will not work:

```
case A = 1, A + 1 of
    3 ->
        ok;
    _->
        nop
end.

% returns syntax error before: ','
```