# Generating a random rule for property based test

Tags: erlang, quickcheck, triq

I am using [Triq](https://github.com/krestenkrab/triq) (erlang quickcheck) and I am having trouble generating a set of *nice* rules for my program.

What I want to generate are things that looks like this:

```
A -> B
```

where I would like to provide `A` and the size of `B`, with latter not having any dupicates.

For example, if I say generate me rules with L.H.S. of `[a]` and R.H.S. of size 4 (ie. `A = [a]` and `size(B) = 4`) I  would like to get something like this:

```
{rule, [a], [1,2,4,5]}
{rule, [a], [a,d,c,e]}
{rule, [a], [q,d,3,4]}
```

Note, I don't want *any* dupicates in B (this is the part I'm having trouble with). Also, it doesn't really matter what *B* is made up of - it can be anything as long as it is distinct and without dupicates.

My spec is far too messy to show here, so I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Triq, but in PropEr and Quviq's Qickcheck you can use [`?SUCHTHAT`](http://proper.softlab.ntua.gr/FAQ.html) conditions that filter 'bad' instances.

If a generated instance does not satisfy a ?SUCHTHAT constraint it is discarded and not counted as a valid test. You could use this mechanism to generate lists of the specified size (i.e. what PropEr calls 'vectors') and then discard those that have duplicates, but I think that too many instances would then be discarded (see also the link).

It is usually more efficient to tinker with the generator so that **all** instances are valid, in your case by e.g. generating <s>(3)</s> X-times as many elements, removing duplicates and keeping as many as you need. This can still fail, and it will fail, so you need to guard against it.

Here is a generator for your case, in PropEr, together with a dummy property:

```
-module(dummy).

-export([rule_prop/0]).

-include_lib("proper/include/proper.hrl").

-define(X, 5).

rule_prop() ->
  ?FORALL(_, rule_gen(integer(), 4, integer()), true).

rule_gen(A, SizeB, TypeB) ->
  ?LET(
     EnoughB,
     ?SUCHTHAT(
        NoDupB,
        ?LET(
           ManyB,
           vector(?X * SizeB, TypeB),
           no_dups(ManyB)
          ),
        length(NoDupB) >= SizeB
       ),
     begin
       B = lists:sublist(EnoughB, SizeB),
       {rule, A, B}
     end).

no_dups([]) ->
  [];
no_dups([A|B]) ->
  [A | no_dups([X || X <- B, X =/= A])].
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question: why do we generate 3 times as many? Is the number three special, or you mean that we just need to generate more than needed?

Comment: No it isn't, it just "ensures" that enough distinct elements will remain after removing duplicates.

Comment: Will this _always_ generate something?

Comment: Oh, ok I finally got it. You generate only bigger lists than necessary, and then making them smaller. Thank you very much.

Comment: One more question, what is the `begin` and `end` block construction you are using here? Where is it in the docs?

Comment: Hm... it seems like I'm getting "Error: Couldn't produce an instance that satisfies all strict constraints after 50 tries." I am using PropEr.

Comment: For `begin` `end` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125277/what-is-begin-end-in-erlang-used-for).

Comment: This means that `?SUCHTHAT` failed with just 3 times as many elements. For lists of 10 unique `integer()` elements, 50 elements seems to be ok, but this is probably also a bug of PropEr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108535/discussion-between-drozzy-and-aronisstav).